# Why is the destructor of the derived class called?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, destructor, virtual-functions

I have a simple program:

```
struct B
{
    virtual ~B() {}
};

struct D : public B
{
    ~D() {}
};
```

So, when I call

```
B* b = new D;

b->~B();
```

why is the destructor of the derived class called? It's virtual but we call the destructor by name, or is there a hidden name of the destructor which is the same for all classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The destructor does not have a name, per se. For a class `C`, the syntax `~C` is used to refer to the single, nameless destructor.

In your case, `~B` therefore simply means "the destructor." Because it's virtual, dynamic dispatch happens at runtime at the destructor of `D` gets called.

If you did this instead:

```
b->B::~B();
```

it would disable dynamic dispatch (like any other qualified call does) and you'd call `B`'s destructor only.